# VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration not operational with VirtualBox

Tags: macos, virtualbox, bios, hardware-virtualization

I am trying to install OS X with VirtualBox, on my Windows 7 laptop. I see the following error message:

```
VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration has been enabled, but is not operational. 
Certain guests (e.g. OS/2 and QNX) require this feature.

Please ensure that you have enabled VT-x/AMD-V properly in the BIOS of your
host computer.
```

After this message, the boot fails with a critical error.

I am using Lenovo X201 Tablet as the host machine.

What should I check and how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have TXT enabled in the bios?

Comment: @Paul I enabled it and now it is working! I am installing Mac OS X... Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.  I was expecting you to tell me it was enabled, and I was going to answer with "disable it" in order to get VT-x working.  I guess they updated the bios.  How do you want to close off this question, shall I answer it anyway and you'll accept?

Comment: You can self answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer :) if you wish

Comment: @Paul Oops, it wasn't TXT; I enabled something else, callsed "Intel Virtualization Technology".

Comment: Cool - just for the record, can you tell me if TXT is enabled or disabled?

Comment: @Paul I don't know what TXT is, but Intel Active Management Technology is disabled. Intel VT-d Feature is also disabled.

Comment: Trusted eXecution Technology - it should be an option there somewhere - it can interfere with vt-x.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Self Answer:

In the BIOS (In my machine, hold F1 during boot-up.) I enabled CPU > Intel Virtualization Technology. Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I also stumbled into this issue on a Lenovo T420s.  I had virtualization enabled and TXT disabled, but still got this error.  The Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager for Android was locking the virtualization subsystem and wouldn't let either virtualbox or Virtual PC use it. Uninstall or disable it, and you should be fine.

More info: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=49479

Answer (score 0):

With Dell BIOS version A03 (dated 12/18/2006), it was F2 to get into the BIOS at boot and then

POST Behaviour -> Virtualization -> Enabled

Answer (score 0):

Another possible avenue: I have a Dell XPS 730 (BIOS firmware 1.0.6) with Windows 10 Pro. I had the Virtualization "enabled" in the BIOS, and Windows would not recognize the firmware as having it enabled (witnessed by running "MSINFO32" on a command prompt.) I had to un-enable it in the BIOS, boot into windows, then re-enable it in the BIOS for windows to recognize it.